# Why is ‘woman’ pluralized in Genesis 3?

Tags: genesis, adam, eden, eve

Chapters 1, 2, 4, 6, 12, 13, 15, and 16 of Genesis 3 have “the women” הָאִשָּׁ֣ה as one of the characters included in the conversation.
Both the serpent and YHWH address the women, the women reply, and both Adam and YHWH talk about the women.
The rest of the conversation reads as if it includes only four characters: the serpent, the woman, the man/Adam, and YHWH.

Comment: Please explain this.  I am only seeing the singular הָֽאִשָּׁ֖ה for woman.

Comment: The first occurrence of the plural נָשִׁ֑ים (translated wives) is in Gen. 4:19.

Comment: I am using the Interlinear Bible app (by Martin Loch). There it is translated as “the women” except for in 3:13 where YHWH addresses ‘the woman’.

Comment: Now I have checked other digital interlinear versions (I recently moved and have not found the box with the right books yet) and see that it must be an error/idiosyncracy of text presented in the app I was using. I will see if I can erase the question. Thanks all anyway!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.